# FirebaseUI email sign in link opens new browser tab

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, tabs

I am using FirebaseUI Email link sign in.

Clicking the link returns me to the correct page (where I began the sign in process) but not to the same tab. A new tab is opened and I am left with the first tab open, showing the message,

> A sign-in email with additional instructions was sent to user@example.com. Check your email to complete sign-in.

Does this depend on my own browser settings or can I target the initial tab?

If not, can I close the initial tab from the new tab?

Comment: That does open it in a new tab. Best you can do is close the current (opened after authentication) or prompt the user to do so and [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29220735/script-to-close-other-tabs-or-browser/29220934) a way to close any other tab.

Comment: Okay thanks. I'll give a try to the method you linked (I found that answer too!)

If that's just the way it is, why not put your comment into an answer and I'll accept it...

Comment: Still, that is a bit weird that FirebaseUI leaves the old tab open like that. There should be a way to target the opening tab.